# Scrollable view over background widget in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, listview, scroll

I want to make something similar to the Google weather app where there is a background image displayed underneath scrollable content, but the content starts off the screen and only comes into view when the user scrolls.
[image: Google weather app]

My first idea was to use a `Stack` with a `ListView` as a child. This works in that the content is scrollable and the image is in the background, but the content does not start off the bottom of the screen.
[image: Image of a ListView in Stack]

```dart
import 'package:lottie/lottie.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: HomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  const HomePage({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        body: Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
      child: Stack(
        children: [
          ClipRRect(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12),
            child: Lottie.asset('assets/landscape.zip'),
          ),
          Column(
            children: [
              const Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                child: Text(
                  "Good Morning!",
                  style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                ),
              ),
              Expanded(
                child: ListView(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                  children: [
                    const SizedBox(height: 500),
                    Container(
                      color: Colors.grey[300],
                      height: 200,
                      margin: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 10),
                    ),
                    Container(
                      color: Colors.grey[300],
                      height: 200,
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ],
          )
        ],
      ),
    ));
  }
}
```

If I add a `SizedBox(height: 500)` to the top of the `ListView`, I can scroll the content into view, but obviously when the `SizedBox` reaches the top, the scrolling stops, and if I resize the app the `SizedBox` needs to be resized.
[image: Image of a ListView with SizedBox]

I'm using a Lottie animation instead of an image for the background, but the concept is the same.
Animation from Lottie Files: https://lottiefiles.com/139998-day-and-night-landscape
Lottie Flutter package: https://pub.dev/packages/lottie

Can anyone recommend a good way to achieve the desired effect?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to reproduce the behavior you are describing by using a `Stack` to present the background and the front pages.

The front pages are inside a vertical `PageView` in order to reproduce the stepper effect as the user stops on the entire page.
Using the `ScrollController` of the `PageView` you can detect the transition between the first page (which is empty to display the background) and the second page.

If you bind this to an additional layer that performs the color transition with an `Opacity` widget you have something pretty cool.

It may require a few adjustments to perfectly achieve the design you want but it's pretty neat in my opinion.

PS: Video expires in two days https://streamable.com/obizkq

```
class TestAppHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  TestAppHomePageState createState() => TestAppHomePageState();
}

class TestAppHomePageState extends State<TestAppHomePage> {
  final PageController controller = PageController();
  double currentPageValue = 0.0;

  @override
  void initState() {
    controller.addListener(() {
      if (controller.page != null && controller.page! <= 1.0) {
        setState(() {
          currentPageValue = controller.page!;
        });
      }
    });
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        body: Stack(
      children: [
        Image.asset(
          'assets/background_image.png',
          fit: BoxFit.cover,
          height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
          width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
        ),
        Opacity(
          opacity: currentPageValue,
          child: Container(
            color: Colors.green,
          ),
        ),
        PageView(
          scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
          controller: controller,
          children: const <Widget>[
            CustomPage(
              title: '',
              backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
            ),
            Opacity(
              opacity: currentPageValue,
              child: CustomPage(
                title: 'Page 2',
                backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
              ),
            ),
            CustomPage(
              title: 'Page 3',
              backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ],
    ));
  }
}

class CustomPage extends StatelessWidget {
  final String title;
  final Color backgroundColor;
  const CustomPage(
      {super.key, required this.title, required this.backgroundColor});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      color: backgroundColor,
      child: Center(
        child: Text(title),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Brilliant. Using a PageView was a great idea and it works perfectly. Thanks!